# Stuck on "removing managed software"

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, java, uninstall, deployment

At one time, I had the Software Installation feature in GPO set to install the Java 7 update 11 MSI installer. Then, I removed it with the removal method "immediately uninstall the software from users and computers".

Now, I have a windows 2008 R2 server that gets stuck on "removing managed software java 7 update 11".

Normally, I would bypass this by unplugging the network connection, doing a hard reset, starting back up, then running the Microsoft Fix It tool to remove any remnants of Java. However, the Fix It tool won't run on this operating system.

If I try to reinstall Java by running the MSI file, I get the message:

> User 'SYSTEM' has previously initiated an install for product "Java 7
>   update 11'. That user will need to run that install again before they
>   can use that product.
>
> Error 1704. An installation for Java 7 update 11 is currently
>   suspended.

If I run the installer a second time, it installs, and I can uninstall it from "programs and features" in the control panel.

However, at startup, I still get stuck on the "removing managed software" message.

What can I do? Can I cancel the uninstallation somehow? Or manually remove Java? (The JavaRa tool didn't work).

[edit]: Would this be an appropriate next step?

> enter regedit and find navigate to the following:
>
> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Appmgmt`
>
> Then find the correct key, this is easy to do by looking at each key’s
>   “Deployment Name“. Once you have found the correct key simply delete
>   it and reboot. The computer will boot normally now and you can then
>   remove the offending software via Control Panel.

Source: http://philipwilmot.co.uk/blog/2009/12/remove-failed-removal-of-deployed-software/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick:

> enter regedit and find navigate to the following:
>
> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Appmgmt
>
> Then find the correct key, this is easy to do by looking at each key’s
>   “Deployment Name“. Once you have found the correct key simply delete
>   it and reboot. The computer will boot normally now and you can then
>   remove the offending software via Control Panel.

Source: http://philipwilmot.co.uk/blog/2009/12/remove-failed-removal-of-deployed-software/

Comment: Perfect solution. Did the trick for me even on a Windows Server 2012 VM.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: **Remove any in-progress installations.**

Launch Windows Registry Editor.

Windows XP: Choose Start > Run, and type regedit in the Open textbox and click OK.
    Windows Vista: Choose Start then type regedit in the Search box and press return.

Navigate to one of the following registry keys:

32-bit editions of Windows:
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Inprogress

64-bit editions of Windows:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Inprogress

If the Inprogress key exists, then delete it.

Solution 2: **Unregister and then reregister the Windows Installer Service.**

**Unregister the Windows Installer Service**

Windows XP: Choose Start > Run. Type msiexec /unreg in the Search field and press Enter.

Windows Vista: Choose Start, type msiexec /unreg in the Search field and press Enter.

**Register the Windows Installer Service**

Windows XP: Choose Start > Run. Type msiexec /regserver and click OK.

Windows Vista:  Choose Start, type msiexec /regserver in the Search field and press Enter.

Comment: This is server 2008, not a client O/S, plus this is for software pushed out for group policy. The registry entry is in a different place than for what you described for XP/vista.